# Who has used PHP's OAuth?

Tags: php, oauth

https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.setup.php

who has used it ?  Is it OAuth 1.0 or 2.0?

I'm going to write an OAuth solution for my project but not sure whether I should write from scratch or use this extension.  Is there other good PHP OAuth library  you recommend?  I'm looking for solid library and ease of installation.

Comment: It's oAuth 1.0a - implementation with fixed session hijack hole in the 1.0 version of the protocol: http://hueniverse.com/2009/04/explaining-the-oauth-session-fixation-attack/

There is one PHP library I know of, that has implemented oauth 2.0, but I haven't used it: http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it OAuth 1.0 or 2.0?

It's 1.0.  2.0 is still a draft.  I'm not aware of any 2.0 consumers in PHP.

I've used it before.  A major downside to it, when compared to other implementations, is that the HTTP adapter is *completely* opaque.  You can't touch it at all.  If you need to do anything advanced, like, say, set proxy information, you're totally out of luck.

Consider [PEAR's OAuth](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth/redirected), which uses [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/) as the underlying HTTP adapter, or [Zend_Oauth_Consumer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html), which uses [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) as the underlying HTTP adapter.  Both libraries are full-featured and the underlying HTTP adapters are both powerful and useful for all kinds of requests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it in all my social apps API calls for facebook, linkedin Twitter and others, it is very useful, though there are some specific tweeks you need to do for different services to work. I'm using it currently with Xampp 1.7.7 on windows.
It works well but it took me some time to get it to work properly, prepare to spend a lot of time on it, especially since documentation for all the services is not very good.
Current support is for PHP 5.3, I am looking for PHP 5.4 windows version and havn't found yet.

Answer (score 0):

The official OAuth 2 page - http://oauth.net/2/ - is currently linking to this php oauth2 implementation on github: https://github.com/quizlet/oauth2-php